# how to manage the large no of table of multi site in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have one website in wordpress from its I gave access to other user for create their own website but when he crate their site then 11 tables are made in database. And I have almost 10.5 millions user,so when they all create their sites then main database has around 120 millions table due to this our main website has down.
So, please give suggestion how to overcome this problem. Kindly give response as soon as possible.

Thanks,
Rajesh Mishra
CIET

Answer (score 0):

I run a multisite with around 20k sites at the moment and add around 7k each year. We deal with the scale in part by using [Multi DB](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-db/) but there are a few others like [ShardDB](https://bcc.wordpress.org/plugins/shardb/) that let you split things up. That helps considerably.

I have seen other people use subdomains and chunk their WP multisite installs into more manageable (but separate) installs on an X sites per install per server basis.

I have not pursued the route of having WP generate fewer tables.

Depending on the level of user activity in the dashboard and with authoring content you'll have a really large load on the server. WPMU Dev has at least an [introduction to the large scale (although still only 500k sites) multisite conversation](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/scaling-wordpress-wpmu-buddypress-like-edublogs/).